# RenderScript acting weird and returning nothing

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm using renderscript and when i write a kernel, at first it is acting ok. but when i change the kernel and rebuild the project it returns nothing. anybody knows why? It just return a blank photo and nothing else.

Comment: You'll need to provide far more information before anyone can offer suggestions or help.  See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you post your source code, so that we can understand what can be wrong with it? :)

Comment: I have fixed it. the problem for me was targetSdkVersion 24 . i found out that in android 7, there has been a lot of changes for renderscript, so i have changed it to targetSdkVersion 22 and it fixed the issue. the code was the sample code from documents of google. @LarrySchiefer

Comment: I have fixed it. the problem for me was targetSdkVersion 24 . i found out that in android 7, there has been a lot of changes for renderscript, so i have changed it to targetSdkVersion 22 and it fixed the issue. the code was the sample code from documents of google. @cmaster11

Comment: Thank you very much for the sharing :) Can you post a small link to where you found these changes? For further info

Comment: Yes sure. i've updated the post with an answer. i hope it is useful for someone else. @cmaster11

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it. the problem for me was targetSdkVersion 24 . i found out that in android 7, there has been a lot of changes **(NEW FEATURES)** for renderscript, so i have changed it to targetSdkVersion 22 and it fixed the issue. I tried to do a simple filter, and after using the filter it showed me nothing in the imageview. But when i changed the targetSdkVersion to 22 it fixed the problem and i could see the filtered image in the imageview. here is the code i've used:

```
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) filtered(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

uchar4 out = in;
 out.r = 255 - in.r;
 out.g = 255 - in.g;
 out.b = 255 - in.b;
 return out;
}
```

if you are interested you can try it with the targetSdkVersion 24 and 22. and here is the code for java part:

```
public void imageFilter(Bitmap bmp) {

    doAllocation();

    operationBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

    int height = operationBitmap.getHeight();
    int width = operationBitmap.getWidth();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, width + " x " + height, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ScriptC_cnn cnnScript = new ScriptC_cnn(rs);
    cnnScript.forEach_filtered(allocIn, allocOut);

    allocOut.copyTo(operationBitmap);
    selectedImagePreview.setImageBitmap(operationBitmap);
    rs.destroy();
}

public void doAllocation() {

        allocIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, originalBitmap,
                Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        allocOut = Allocation.createTyped(rs,
                allocIn.getType());
}
```

and you can see the renewed document of google in the developer.android website. here is the link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#writing-an-rs-kernel

you can see that for a mapping kernel you can use RS_KERNEL instead of attribute((kernel)). and as google mentioned RS_KERNEL is a macro defined automatically by RenderScript for your convenience:

```
#define RS_KERNEL __attribute__((kernel))
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "shahryar.com.cellularneuralnetwork"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true;
    renderscriptTargetApi 16;
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

And i have used renderscriptTargetApi 16 according this line in the google's document: Valid values for this setting are any integer value from 11 to the most recently released API level. If your minimum SDK version specified in your application manifest is set to a different value, that value is ignored and the target value in the build file is used to set the minimum SDK version.

**Note**: this is the gradle version which is working now for me.

Comment: This issue is curious. So, it works with 22 and not with 24, right? No code changes involved?

Comment: Yes right. no code changes. you can test it. i've put the whole code for testing. test it and you can see. and by the way i'm using android studio 2.1.3 . with 24 you cannot see the resulted filter in the imageview. and the imageview is like that it is blank. @cmaster11

Comment: Thank you, I'll analyze the issue!

Comment: Oh right, where are you testing the whole thing? Which device?

Comment: emulator. @cmaster11

Comment: And only targetSdkVersion affect the issue right? And this is using RenderScript support lib?

Comment: I don't know if ONLY targetSdkVersion is effecting this issue or not (i have not tested everything). but when i changed the targetSdkVersion it fixed the problem for me. and yes i'm using the support lib. why? do you have the same problem?

Comment: Just want to make sure if this is a bug in the support lib so that we can fix it. With build-tools 24.0.1, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue yet. What is the emulator API level, is it running Android N? Did you specify "renderscriptTargetApi" in gradle? More information will be useful, thanks!

Comment: Also, the logcat for 24 will also be helpful.

Comment: @MiaoWang i will Update my post with the gradle. and no i use emulator api23 and genymotion samsung galaxy s6.

Comment: @MiaoWang i have tested it with targetSdkVersion 24 now. it is working. but believe me it didn't work before. And i have encountered this problem 2 times in the past 2 weeks. i have posted another question before for my problem. and I'm sure that this problem exist.

Comment: @MiaoWang here is the link for my before question that renderscript acted weird that time too. see the date.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019602/renderscript-acting-weird-and-picasso-acting-weird